# Better way to add custom controls to your project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

There are groups of customized user-interface components, freely available for VS 2010 Express. They are called "themes". Here you have a video showing how these themes can be added to a VB project:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ec9GZaPMGqE

I would like to be able to apply a "theme" to my already existing application, but doing so would require me to manually replace all the elements in my form with the newly imported ones. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Themes? Can you please be much more specific regarding what you mean exactly? (also regarding the programming framework: Winforms, WPF, ASP.NET...)

Comment: PS: a so "peculiar" question sounds familiar to me. And the person who asked such a thing before didn't have any idea at all about VB.NET. Is this your case too? (from your profile, it seems that you don't have too much .NET experience) -> being 100% honest is the best way to speed up any communication process :)

Comment: I'm using Visual Basic Express 2010 and my program is basically just a calculator. I'm not sure what vb.net is. I just want to apply a theme to my program but after following some tutorials, it seems I would have to replace all the things on the form manually. Does this answer your question? Yeah I don't have any experience working with Microsoft stuff, so I don't know what all those frameworks are or if I'm even using them. I just downloaded visual basic 2010 express started coding away.

Comment: "Theme" is not part of the .NET languages; that's why I asked for further explanations (to understand what you mean exactly with this word). Please, update your question with all the relevant information (e.g., before and after pics or links to relevant sites/codes/videos/pictures dealing with what you call "theme"). What you have is a bunch of controls with properties (like any OO language has, in Microsoft and anywhere else): you can change the properties of each control. But there is no global synchronisation on the lines of what I understand as "theme" (e.g., make all the controls "blue").

Comment: I have seen the video and now things are much clearer. The guy in the video is basically adding a new class (well... copying it from internet); "theme" is not a .NET recognised designation, but something this guy wrote. This class can contain anything (it is basically a bunch of code). Please, forget about this video and this idea of relying on themes; improve your VB.NET knowledge and code whatever changes you need (or ask here for help).

Comment: So you don't know how to do this?

Comment: ?! Yes. Add a new class (if you don't know how to do it; the video is quite descriptive). But for adding a new class, you need it to contain code; and you should write this code. This whole idea does not make any sense. The guy in this video has made up a name "theme" and showed you how to add a new class (a new file) to your solution.

Comment: Haha, I already imported the classes. I don't think you understand my question. After importing the classes, I have to drag the new elements onto the form. I'm trying to see if there's some code I can change instead of having to replace all my UI elements graphically. Like, is there a place where visual basic express instantiates all these form elements? I would be able to change the classes there. But I can't find anything like that.

Comment: Your question was: "how I import a theme". My answer: "there is no such a thing". After seeing the video, I have understood that you meant "adding some code" (written by a guy who has shot a video and called it "theme"). And now you start talking about "instantiating"... ?! This has got a bit too long, I think. I have done my work by clarifying what you meant with "themes". If you still need more help, you should better wait for the next helper (I have promised myself to not waste too much time unnecessarily).

Comment: PS: note that your accepted-answers ratio is really low and that I usually ignore people like this (firmly believe in helping only those deserving it). But I found your question so "peculiar" that I preferred to clarify the "theme" issue.

Comment: As said, don't think that people like you deserve to get any help; but, after reading your update, I felt a bit sorry... So I have rewritten it such that your ideas are properly transmitted. Feel free to change it back in case of not liking my improvements.

Comment: Thanks! I like the edits you made. Hopefully someone can help me apply these themes without having to switch out all my controls :)

Comment: You are welcome. The more clear you are, the more likely is that someone might feel like helping you (because this is what you are requesting: help, which would be generously provided by someone).

Comment: @FranciscoBárcena Please look at my answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22128032/1842065