# Can I quickly replace my components to a custom theme's components?

Tags: vb.net

I want to improve the look of my program by using a custom created theme like this: http://www.mpgh.net/forum/33-visual-basic-programming/492570-biesis-vb-net-theme-archive.html

The thing is I have at least 30 components already with custom names, text, etc on my form. Redoing them would be a pain.

So, is there an easy way to do this?

I appreciate any replies.

Comment: the design step is a beautiful thing, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, though not recommended (depending on the complexity of your application).  Make sure you've got a full **backup** of your project *before* trying this.

1. With your project still open, close all open files and hit `Ctrl + H`.
2. In `Find what` enter the **fully qualified name** of the control to replace.
3. In `Replace with` enter the **fully qualified name** of the custom control.
4. Set `Look in` to `Current Project`.
5. Check `Match case` and `Match whole word`.
6. Click `Replace All` button.

[image: Find and Replace]

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what your custom controls are. Based on previous experience with Devexpress, for example, replacing control class names, as suggested by @Bjorn, will only work for some of their controls. Others will not behave expected, because they rely on sub-controls, generated automatically by the designer, whenever a control is placed on the form.

The best approach as I see it now, would be to redesign your form with placeholder controls (no specific binding to any UI framework), then replace, or embed the actual controls at runtime. You should be most flexible this way, and even able to inject sub-controls (to solve the problem with some Devexpress controls).